# REST base service clients sharing STS issued token

Tags: rest, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

What prevents REST based service clients to share the STS issued token with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bearer token are like passwords and can be shared or replayed.

[Codeplex Link](http://startersts.codeplex.com/discussions/242297)